# In javascript XMLHttpRequest, changing POST request to GET request

Tags: javascript, post, web, get, xmlhttprequest

My javascript library is sending payload data from client browser to web server.

And, intermittently, I find a weird situation in Web server logs.
When sending data from the client through my library, using the POST method of XHR and the GET method is sent intermittently with the same target URL.

My library code is as follows...

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()

xhr.onreadystatechange = function (event) {
  if (xhr.readyState === 4 /** responseText is not available yet */) {
    const statusCode = xhr.status
    const responseText = xhr.responseText

    if (responseValidator(statusCode, responseText)) {
    if (successCallback) successCallback(xhr)
  } else {
    const error = new Error(`${ErrorType.INVALID_RESPONSE}: ${statusCode}`)
    Logger.error(error)
    handleServerError(payloads)
    if (failureCallback) failureCallback(error)
  }
 }
}

xhr.open('POST', url, true /** async */)
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain; charset=utf8')
xhr.withCredentials = true
xhr.timeout = timeoutMillis
xhr.ontimeout = function (event) {
  const error = new Error(`${ErrorType.REQUEST_TIMEOUT} (${timeoutMillis} millis)`)
  Logger.error(error)
  if (failureCallback) failureCallback(error)
}
xhr.onerror = function (e) {
  handleServerError(payloads)
}
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(payloads))
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Well that sounds like your server is returning a redirect for the requested URL ...

Comment: Possibly nothing to do with your code and just a bot that has found the URL.

Comment: What situation do server(nginx) redirect to ??